# Passing java objects from jsp page to servlet through html forms

Tags: java, forms, jsp, http, servlets

I have a scenario in which I pass the list of objects through jsp's, its one of the attribute(name) is displayed in the drop down menu,now I want only that object should be passed again to the servlet which is selected in drop down menu while submitting the form.

What will be the best way to do it? As in forms everything is passes as string and get(through request parameter) as strings only?

I know i can pass the name and then in the servlet I can check for that name in the list of objects.But there must be some alternative solution and I am looking for that

Answer (score 0):

Here are the alternatives:

- Convert the values into strings and embed them in the HTML etc that gets sent to the user's browser.  When the user "submits", send the strings back to the web server as request parameters where the servlet can turn the strings back into values.
- Put the values into the request's `Session` object, and have the servlet fish them out.
- Pass the values to the browsers via set-cookie, and then have the servlet extract the cookie values out of the request.

Of these, the `Session` approach is the most secure.  If you put the values into cookies or the web form, then they can be read by the user and (maybe) changed.

You could pass a "name" I guess ... but what you are doing is reinventing the wheel of the `Session` object.

Comment: I cant use  a session or a cookie,as till the time of form submitting I do not know which object is selected in the drop down,as I need only that object in the action servlet,so I cant use session before form submitting and after form submitting,I dont have an object so no point of using sessions.

Comment: yes,values  can be passed as strings but then I have to pass multiple values of the selected object.How will I pass multiple values from the selected object?

Comment: You didn't say that the user needed to select one of the objects.  But that's not a problem.  Store key-value pairs in the Session, and put the key into the selector.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be the only possible feasable solution.